# How to use user jaeger in node js when both installed in kubernetes?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, jaeger, opentracing

I am trying to implement Jaeger in the node js project. I have deployed this node js project(using docker image) and Jaegaer in k8s (kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes/master/all-in-one/jaeger-all-in-one-template.yml)

Both are working individually but traces are not visible in the service

```
var initTracer = require('jaeger-client').initTracer;
const opentracing = require("opentracing");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var config = {
  'serviceName': 'user-service',
  'local_agent': {
                'reporting_host': 'jaeger',
                'reporting_port': '6831',
            },
  'reporter': {
    'logSpans': true    
  },
  'sampler': {  
    'type': 'probabilistic',
    'param': 1.0
  }
};
var options = {
  'tags': {
    'user-service': '1.1.2'
  }
};

var tracer = initTracer(config, options);
opentracing.initGlobalTracer(tracer);

console.log(tracer);

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));



app.get('/users/:id',(req, res) => {
    const span = tracer.startSpan('get user by user_id');

    res.send(JSON.stringify('hello'));

  span.log({'event': 'request_end'});
    span.finish();
});

// Set up server
const server = app.listen(8000, () => {
    let host = server.address().address;
    let port = server.address().port;

    console.log('Service_1 listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: Can you share a Kubernetes manifest for your Nodejs project (i.e. pod.yaml or deployment.yaml)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the logs being generated by your pods?

In my case I got the following

> ERROR Failed to flush spans in reporter: error sending spans over UDP:
>   Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://jaeger-agent, packet size: 984,
>   bytes sent: undefined

Changing it to jaeger-agent worked for me.

Also if it helps I have declared this under my jaeger image in docker-compose.yml:

```
 + ports: - "5775:5775/udp" - "6831:6831/udp" - "6832:6832/udp" - "5778:5778" - "16686:16686" - "14268:14268" - "9411:9411"`
```